# Javascript highlighting different column at a time in a table

Tags: javascript, html

Im looking for a way to try to highlight same value in one column only but this code highlighting all of the value that show in the different column what.

What I want is that the result will only highlight the column 1, not column 2 or 3 in the code, but if there is a the same value in the column then it will be highlighted as like column 1.

What I expected

Column 1 **Santo**, **Santo**, Salad

Column 2 mono, polo , mana

Column 3 **Mono**, **Mono**, Plastine

The one in the bold is for the one that will get the highlight text

```js
    $(function() {
        var tablecols = $("#highlight tbody tr td");
        var colValues = [];
        tablecols.each(function() { 
            var colValue = $(this).find("b").html();
            if (!colValues[colValue]) {
                var colComposite = new Object();
                colComposite.count = 1;
                colComposite.col = this;
                colValues[colValue] = colComposite;
            } else {
                var colComposite = colValues[colValue];
                if (colComposite.count == 1) {
                    $(colComposite.col).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
                }
                $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
                colComposite.count++;
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="highlight">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>column ke-1</th>
    <th>column ke-2</th>
    <th>column ke-3</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Row 1</th>
        <td><b>Santo</b></td>
        <td><b>Polo</b></td>
        <td><b>Mono</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Row 2</th>
        <td><b>Santo</b></td>
        <td><b>Mono</b></td>
        <td><b>Pala</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Row 3</th>
        <td><b>Salad</b></td>
        <td><b>Plastine</b></td>
        <td><b>Gohom</b></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a1unzkLw/5/

Comment: well, you write `tablecols.each`, what you expected then?

Comment: @appleapple Sorry, i was pretty new to Javascript, and just thought this was enough to highlight one column with same value and also for other column as well